# C code to Java -- char manipulation

Tags: java, c, pointers, char

I need to write this in Java.

Although I know how to read a file, I'm interested in what the 'buff' output is, is the length at the beginning?

```
char              *buff;
unsigned char     *aux;


while(fgets (buff+2, length, fin)){
    len = strlen (buff + 2) + 2;
    aux = (unsigned char *) &len;
    buff[1] = aux[0];
    buff[0] = aux[1];
    ...
    send (sd, buff, len, 0);

}
```

but I don't understand this:

```
aux = (unsigned char *) &len;
buff[1] = aux[0];
buff[0] = aux[1];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't let your `buff` point to allocated memory, the `fgets` will do terrible things.

Comment: @DanielFischer let's hope that it was just redacted in the code sample we are given :)

Comment: What a relief. But indicate that with a comment `/* allocation etc */` in future, we see too much code where no memory is actually allocated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
aux = (unsigned char *) &len;
buff[1] = aux[0];
buff[0] = aux[1];
```

creates a byte-array view of the integer value stored in `len`. In Java, you can't do exactly the same thing, but you can get what you want a couple of ways. The easiest is just with bit masking and shifting:

```
int len = ...;
byte[] buff = ...;
byte[0] = (byte) (len & 0xff);
byte[1] = (byte) ((len >> 8) & 0xff);
```

Another possibility is to use a [`ByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html), but that seems overkill for such a simple operation.

Comment: The C code (if run on a litte-endian machine) stores the length in big-endian order.  Your java code stores it in little endian order, so you've swapped the bytes.

Comment: @ChrisDodd - Yes, the endian-ness of the system is an issue. That's one argument in favor of using a `ByteBuffer`, since you can control that explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

`buff` appears to be the buffer used to read data from the file. It looks like the program makes the assumption that `len` will only be at most two (sizeof(unsigned char)) bytes long. So it packs the lower-most two bytes of `len` into `buf[1:0]` by parsing the address of `len` as an `unsigned char *` and thereby grabbing the lower-most two bytes of `len` and sticking them into the lower-most two bytes of `buff`.

Comment: thanks for the quick response, but i'm not sure how to do it in java

Comment: Fortunately in Java you can do string.length() to determine the length of the string when it is used (presumably on the other side of the send() call), so in this case you can probably get away without this operation entirely.